# How to combine vector paths in Sketch?

Tags: vector, icon, sketch-app

I am trying to combine/flatten a series on paths in Sketch. When I use Layer > Combine I get very unexpected results. I am assuming there is a fairly simple solution that I am missing here, can someone help me out? I have attached examples below (you can especially see the different paths when a gradient is applied). Thanks!

[[image: Layers[1]]

[[image: image[2]]

Answer (score 1):

The way these paths are placed would mean that you can't 'join' them, which would be ideal if you want to keep the icon as stroked paths.

The solution is, like Billy Kerr pointed out, in the 'duplicate' post (it's not really a duplicate, but rather is the solution to your problem). You'll need to convert to outlines (Layer -> Convert to outlines) and then use the pathfinding options (union, substract, intersect, difference), depending on what exactly you'll be trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right, the question is not an exact duplicate, but it will fix the OP's problem if he does that first.